# What is the best way to update data on different panels in a form simultaneously? Timer/Threads?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, timer, refresh

I have an application in Delphi 10.3 which has multiple forms, all holding different data that needs to be periodically updated. I like the idea of having a timer with-in each form that I can control how often it goes off for each panel. Each form lives as a separate pas file and gets instantiated into the mainform as a child.

The more I looked into it, the more it seemed like a bad practice to have too many timers at once. So then I played around with the idea of threads.

Below is a suggestion I found on here from another question about using timers in threads. I create this thread in the baseform that all my other forms inherit, which calls an abstract method to refresh that form instance.

Does this method help my application or just complicate it more? I am better off just using 1 timer in the mainthread to refresh the data?

```
unit TimerThread;

interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;
type
  TRefreshMethod = procedure of object;
type
  TTimerThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTickEvent: THandle;
    Interval:Integer;
  protected
    ARefreshMethod: TRefreshMethod;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    constructor CreateThreadTimer(CreateSuspended: Boolean; TimerInterval:Integer; RefreshMethod: TRefreshMethod = nil);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure FinishThreadExecution;
  end;

implementation

constructor TTimerThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FTickEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
end;

constructor TTimerThread.CreateThreadTimer(CreateSuspended: Boolean; TimerInterval:Integer; RefreshMethod: TRefreshMethod = nil);
begin
  Create(CreateSuspended);
  self.Interval := TimerInterval;
  ARefreshMethod := RefreshMethod;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FTickEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
end;

destructor TTimerThread.Destroy;
begin
  CloseHandle(FTickEvent);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTimerThread.FinishThreadExecution;
begin
  Terminate;
  SetEvent(FTickEvent);
end;

procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if WaitForSingleObject(FTickEvent, Interval) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
    begin
      Synchronize(procedure
        begin
          ARefreshMethod;
        end
      );
    end;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Is there a better standard for this kind of thing that I could be missing?

Comment: There is no problem using many TTimer. The code is much simpler and easy to debug than using threads.

Comment: You can also have a single timer in the main form and then iterate the child forms, calling their respective RefreshMethod.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this idea (**Threads**) complicates your programming more and does not contribute anything if what you need is to update visual elements.

The visual data update part (not thread-safe) should be executed "outside" the Thread (with **Synchronize**), so if most of the thread's work is executed with **Synchronize** (on the main thread) the gain of time does not exist.

I think that ***for this case*** you can use Timers.